# Syntax error on FOREACH ... ENDFOREACH loop

Tags: idl, idl-programming-language

I've got what seems like a simple `FOREACH` loop in IDL (version 8.2.2). For the life of me I can't see why I'm getting a syntax error. I tried replacing the `FOREACH` with a simple `FOR` loop with the same results.

Removing the for loop and running the statements alone works fine (hard coding a single value for `file` of course).

```
FOREACH file, filenames DO BEGIN
   ; A number of
   ; statements that execute
   ; just fine
ENDFOREACH
```

Result:

```
ENDFOREACH
 ^
% Syntax error.
```

This is all running in a script, called with `@myscript`

Perhaps an even simpler example straight from the documentation will help:

I created a script `test.pro`, copy/paste from the docs: http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/BEGIN___END.html, the contents of `test.pro` are:

```
arr = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
FOREACH element, arr DO BEGIN
   PRINT, element
ENDFOREACH
```

Result:

```
IDL> @test
       9

ENDFOREACH
 ^
% Syntax error.
  At: /mydir/test.pro, Line 4
IDL>
```

Comment: Not much that can go wrong here. Is `filesnames` defined and initialized? Is a simple `foreach/for` with maybe just integers working?

Comment: I tried replacing it with a simple `for`/`endfor`, same problem. I've triple checked filesnames, and reproduced it with a simpler example as posted now.

Comment: Are you sure your question is about `idl` and not `idl-programming-language`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch files (called via `@myscript`) can't have compound statements, i.e. with `BEGIN`/`END`. Make it into a procedure/function or a main-level program.

Comment: Ahhhhhh :::a sticky slap to the forehead is heard in the distance:::  Thanks!

Comment: Or, if you really want to, you can use "&" to make it into a compound statement. For example:
    foreach element,arr do begin & blah blah & endforeach
You could use $ to split it across multiple lines.